# The command "npm run build" exited with code 1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, npm

Visual studio will not allow me to publish my ASP.NET core 2 project anymore, creating the following output

> 12/21/2018 1:44:52 PM System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. ---> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window
>   for more details.    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d__127.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---
>
> ===================

I've checked other threads regarding NPM exit with code 1 but neither one seems relevant to me.

I was able to publish project once and the second time I've tried - Got the error. No configuration was changed.

**EDIT**

Npm Error Log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\asmirnov\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v8.11.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle v7@0.1.0~prebuild: v7@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle v7@0.1.0~build: v7@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle v7@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle v7@0.1.0~build: PATH: C:\Users\asmirnov\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\dev\DigiSign\DigiSign2018_UAT\SimplySignWeb\v7\ClientApp\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\UCRT\;C:\Program Files\Intel\UCRT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Rico Suter\NSwagStudio\;C:\Users\asmirnov\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\asmirnov\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\ProgramData\asmirnov\atom\bin;C:\Users\asmirnov\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\asmirnov\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler
9 verbose lifecycle v7@0.1.0~build: CWD: C:\dev\DigiSign\DigiSign2018_UAT\SimplySignWeb\v7\ClientApp
10 silly lifecycle v7@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node scripts/build.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle v7@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle v7@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: v7@0.1.0 build: `node scripts/build.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\asmirnov\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\asmirnov\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid v7@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\dev\DigiSign\DigiSign2018_UAT\SimplySignWeb\v7\ClientApp
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\asmirnov\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v8.11.4
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error v7@0.1.0 build: `node scripts/build.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the v7@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: is there a scripts/build.js file?

Comment: @diogo Yes, the file exists

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure out what the problem is by rinning build in a console, it pointed me to the problem in one of the components that wasn't compiling:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a dash " - " in the file path, in one of the folder names. Renamed the folder and it worked.